# pretty-printing HTML via XSLT without introducing significant whitespace

Tags: html, xslt

Can XSLT be used to turn this:

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <P>aaaa<SPAN>bbbb</SPAN>cccc</P>
    </BODY> 
</HTML>
```

into this:

```
<HTML><!--
 --><BODY><!--
     --><P><!--
         -->aaaa<!--
         --><SPAN><!--
             -->bbbb<!--
         --></SPAN><!--
         -->cccc<!--
     --></P><!--
 --></BODY>
</HTML>
```

?
I'd like to be able to format HTML so that it has a tree-like structure in a text editor without inserting significant whitespace into it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any tool that will do this for you.

XSLT 3.0 gives you the option

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" suppress-indentation="p"/>
```

which will indent only at the upper levels (above `<p>`) where whitespace is insignificant, and will avoid indenting tags below the paragraph level.